# Register raspberry pi to azure via c#

Tags: c#, azure, raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core, azure-iot-hub

I am developing a simple app that need to send and receive some data from azure.
First of all, I have worked with a simulated device(and console app). I have configured my azure portal to work with the this data and everything works well.

At the same time, I checked my sensor with unit-tests and it works fine too.
Now, I want to send some data from my sensors to azure(with Universal App). I tried to work with this link:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/03/connect-your-windows-app-to-azure-iot-hub-with-visual-studio/#BgxLrRq1bXolCitM.97

I choose the device that I worked with in the simulated device and got an error of "unknown host" for the client connect.
Do I need to register my raspberry pi as a device before? How I can send a simple string from known universal app (i.e: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloblinky ) to azure?

I am working with Windows 10 IOT, c#

Thanks!

Update:
I tried to do all what you suggested without success.
Relavant code:

```
    public static async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessageAsync()
    {
        CreateClient();

        var currentTemperature = 20 /*getCurrentTemperature()*/;
        var currentHumidity = 20/*getCurrentHumidity()*/;

        var telemetryDataPoint = new
        {
            deviceId = DeviceId,
            plantID = 7,
            temperature = currentTemperature,
            humidity = currentHumidity,
            userId = 1
        };
        var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(telemetryDataPoint);
        var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
        message.Properties.Add("temperatureAlert", (currentTemperature > 30) ? "true" : "false");

        Debug.WriteLine("{0} > Sending message: {1}", DateTime.Now, messageString);

        await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
    }
```

I don't know how to validate the "sharedAccessKey" on connectionString var

Error(**on await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message) line**):
Exception thrown: 'System.Exception' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
No such host is known. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072AF9)

Comment: Yes, you need to register the device first, using the azure portal or [by code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#create-a-device-identity)

Comment: yes, I worked with this when I created the device for my simulated device app. Can I need to create a new one for the universal app? how can I create a new device with this code? this is a console app and I cant ran it on the raspberry pi. Thanks!

Comment: An error of "unknown host" means your azure iot hub host name is unknown. If you follow [this link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/03/connect-your-windows-app-to-azure-iot-hub-with-visual-studio/#BgxLrRq1bXolCitM.97) it will auto generate a AzureIoTHub.cs file, in this file there is deviceConnectionString var, make sure this is a correct connection string related your azure iot hub.

Comment: @PeterBons we already register the device for the simulated device.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT deviceConnectionString var is define correctly(HostNoame and deviceID, accept to the device shared key that I dont know how I can check it).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT see updated post please

Comment: @PeterBons see updated post please

Comment: I don't see the connection string related code..could you put that...or, could you put your entire code (if feasible) in an online repo.

Comment: @Jay https://github.com/darkMinds/Greenhouse in Greenhouse/I2C/Samples/IoT-I2C/cs Thanks!

Comment: Alright. I will check and if I discover something, I will update my answer below. Although, it is a Sunday so, perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: @Emma.York The issue is not in your code related sending D2C message(maybe in other parts of the project). For checking your connection string you can use a simple console app like [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted#create-a-device-app) and use [device explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer#monitor-device-to-cloud-events) to monitor these messages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do two things here.

First up, connect your device. Details here - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/ConnectDeviceToCloud

Second, connect your app. - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/ConnectAppToCloud

If you run into issues when doing the above two, then, you will be able to ask more specific questions.